# how can I make readthedocs find my configuration file which is already in GitHub project repository root directory?

Tags: python-sphinx, configuration-files, documentation-generation, read-the-docs

I am trying to publish a Python package's documentation on readthedocs.org.

It was being published in previous releases. However, I am getting

"The configuration file required to build documentation is missing from your project."

Despite my .readthedocs.yaml being here: [project Github repository](https://github.com/icebearcanada/cavsiopy)

How can I fix this? I tried pointing to the root directory of the project from the advanced settings on readthedocs, but nothing seems to help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your https://github.com/icebearcanada/cavsiopy/blob/14d80b525657f3b219cf4b8217e76ea99f45d828/.readthedocs.yaml#L1-L6

```yaml
# Read the Docs configuration file for Sphinx projects
# See https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config-file/v2.html for details

# Required
versions:
  - master
```

The helpful link leads to documentation for the accepted keys. You need to change this:

```yaml
# Required
version: 2
```

`versions` is not a valid key. Furthermore, you do not need to specify a branch such as `master` because this configuration file *is* on a branch.